# Is it possible to play a Song from iOS Music Library with AVAudioEngine?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudioengine, mpmediapickercontroller

i have succesfully created a `AVAudioEngine`. It plays local sound-files from the project-directory. But how can I get access to the Music Library on the phone?

Is there a way I can combine `AVAudioEngine` with the `MPMediaPickerController` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes :)

You need to set the `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate` on your `MPMediaPickerController` so you will get notified when the user does something in the `MPMediaPickerController`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediapickercontrollerdelegate) are the methods you can use on `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate`.

As you can see, there is the method [`mediaPicker(_:didPickMediaItems:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediapickercontrollerdelegate/1614657-mediapicker) which is called when the user has picked a song to play. That gives you a  ([`MPMediaItemCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediaitemcollection)) which has `items` containing the songs which the user picked.

You can loop through that collection and look at the individual `items` which are of type [`MPMediaItem`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem).

Finally each `MPMediaItem` has an `assetURL` which you can to create the individual nodes in your `AVAudioEngine`.

So...something along the lines of:

#### Where You Create Your MPMediaPickerController

```
let mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .anyAudio)
mediaPicker.delegate = self
present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

#### Delegate Methods

```
public func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
  for item in mediaItemCollection.items {
     if let assetURL = item.assetURL {
        //There you go :)
     }
  }
}
```

Remember to `dismiss` the `MPMediaPickerController` when done with it (and remember to do so when canceling too (there is a delegate method for that too)).

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: now the Question is how do I put the assetURL into the AVAudioEngine?  AVAudioFile *file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:_item.assetURL error:nil];    -> this doesn't working.

Comment: OK, interesting :) do you get any errors in return? What if you pass it an error object instead of `nil`, just to see if it returns any errors to you. Where do you declare your `AVAudioEngine` instance? It should be as a property on your class (just to make sure).

Comment: yes I have it as a property :)   in my mediapicker delegate method there is no item with a assetURL found. Maybe songs from Music Library have no assetURL?

Comment: Ah...I have a theory now:) . Maybe you are trying to pick/play a song that is not stored locally on your device? `MPMediaPickerController` has a property called `showCloudItems`, could you set that to false/NO so you only see items that actually are on your device. That should guarantee that you have an `assetURL`.

Comment: Thats it!  I had forgotten to download a few songs on this testDevice! Yesterday I had used another device where I had downloaded some songs ;)  showCloudItems = NO is a good trick to avoid this . Thank you +1

Comment: Fantastic! I just remembered the `showCloudItems` property and now I remember that I had the same issue when I was trying to get this to work :) glad you got it working in the end.